# how to make sure a user only clicks on something once on my webpage like a "like" button

Tags: php, javascript, session

I have javascript/php/ and mysql on my webpage so any ideas will really help. 
USE CASE: anyone visits webpage and clicks like button and thats it he cant continue to keep clicking the "like" button. Should I use session in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store, store, store. When someone, let's say logged in through a Session, likes/comments... then store the id of that person, in a specific row, you could store `IP` and `USER Agent` all together in database, then it is as easy as fetching that row, and searching the user's `id` to check, if he/she has already liked or not.

Just an illustration..

```
if($_POST['check']) {

$like = $_POST['like'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//mysql_query goes here

}
```

Comment: $_SESSION['id']     = $q;
  $_SESSION['ip_address'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $_SESSION['user_agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $_SESSION['last_access'] = time();

Comment: So use what i posted above and store in the database? that makes sense

Comment: @Thefirstkilla Yes, It does. except for the `time()`, because, if you are going to store ip, and browser, then the time is pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

i havent done any of this in a long time, but i assume there is some kind of way of disabling a button once clicked, maybe that helps http://forums.asp.net/t/1235703.aspx/1 using js

Comment: hopefully pretty straight forward :)

Comment: Thanks but I need a persistent save longer than day so i believe php Noob is on the right track. His answer will allow me to check if the person already clicked a button or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to treat it as an idempotent operation combined with a cookie cache that stashes the fact that something has been "liked".

Liking something is an operation that says, "*ensure this user has liked this thing*".

After they click the button, lock it off with JS that dispatches the AJAX to the server, then stash the like in a cookie that stores an array of liked objects. If the page gets refreshed, don't make it clickable unless the like is absent from the cookies *and* the SQL table of "likes". (So you have support for locking it off server-side and client-side).

Don't forget to invalidate cached likes in the client-side cookie if it doesn't line up with backing-store "truth".

This should be a sufficiently elaborate way to go about it.